# YouTube iFrame API - Enable Native Controls

Tags: html, ipad, iframe, youtube

is there any way to have native controls display with the YouTube Iframe API?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible on the iPad since all the playback is handled by iOS itself.

You might want to try set `controls=1` for the `playerVars` in your function if you are using the HTML5 player like so:

> ```
> playerVars: {
>     'controls': 1
> },
> ```

See [this google developers page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player) for more information about the iFrame API.